# display images with forEach javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Images in the folder "images" aren't displayed in the view... the path is correct, browser don't display any error, can somebody help me please?

```
function Abstract() {

    let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img')];

    images.forEach((img, idx) => {
        img.style.backgroundImage = `url(../images/${idx+1}.jpeg)`
    })

    return (
       <div className="slider">
           <div className="slider-inner">

               <div className="item">
                   <div className="img">
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div className="item">
                   <div className="img">
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div className="item">
                   <div className="img">
                   </div> 
               </div>
               
           </div>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly : 1) It takes existing elements with the class img. Is there such elements in your html ? 2) It sets the background of these elements. If none you image is set to nobody. 3) It returns new elements. These elements being new they don't have a background set

Comment: You shouldn't be using `querySelectorAll` with React.

Answer (score 0):

[Because of the way React works](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) it's generally bad practice (there are exceptions, depending on your cause) to use native DOM methods to check and update the elements. It will tangle with the way that React manages state/DOM updates, and the result is a non-functioning component as you've found out.

Ideally you need an array of image names that you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over to produce the JSX your component returns.

This is a working example based on your code but I've done four modifications.

1. I've created an array of image names.
2. I've created a parent component for `Abstract`, and passed the array from the parent into `Abstract` as a prop. (Note: this wasn't completely necessary, you could have declared the array in `Abstract` but this seemed more appropriate).
3. In `Abstract` I `map` over the array to create an `img` for each element with a specific class based on its name (`image image1` etc).
4. I use CSS to define the background image information (I've used dummy images here).

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Pass in the images array as a prop
// `map` over the array to create some images
// adding a new `className` to the image using the image name
function Abstract({ images }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {images.map(src => {
        const cn = `image ${src}`;
        return <img className={cn} />
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const images = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3'];

// Pass in the images array as a prop to `Abstract`
function Example({ images }) {
  return <Abstract images={images} />
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example images={images} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.image { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.image1 { background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/100x100/666/ff0'); }
.image2 { background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/100x100/999/ff0'); }
.image3 { background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/100x100/222/ff0'); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try :

```
let idx=1
return (
   <div class="slider">
       <div class="slider-inner">

           <div class="item">
               <div class="img" style="background-image: `url(../images/${idx++}.jpeg)`">
               </div>
           </div>

// repeat 3 times    
       
       </div>
   </div>
)
```

Comment: I tryed to add first an image in the div "img" in the css but it doesn't work